# Laravel belongs to throwing undefined error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, relationship

I have 2 models.

User:

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    protected $table = 'users';

    public function group () 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Group');
    }
}
```

And Group:

```
class Group extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'groups';
}
```

The user table has a foreign key on the `group` column which references the `id` on the group table.

Schema may help

```
Schema::table('users', function ($table) {

    $table->foreign('group')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('groups')
        ->onDelete('cascade');

});
```

When I try to get the group of a user using:

`User::find(1)->group()->name`

I get the error

`Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$name`

Group Schema as requested:

```
Schema::create('groups', function ($table) {

    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->integer('permission');

});
```

Here are some screens:

**users** table

[image]

**groups** table:

[image]

And the **users** table FK

[image]

**EDIT**

@Cryode solved it for me in a chat session. The problem was that I had conflicting names. The model method used the same name as the column name (`group`). Simply changing the column name in the database solved the issue.

Comment: Show us the Group schema.

Comment: Ive added the group schema @TimWithers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After helping through chat, the problem was that there was an existing column called `group`, and the relationship method was also called `group`, so the table column value was taking precedence over the relationship method.

Renaming the relationship method, or the `group` column to something like `group_id` are both suitable solutions (I'd suggest the `group_id` route).

---

*Original answer:*

You retrieve the group through a magic property, not directly from the method.

```
echo User::find(1)->group->name;
```

If you retrieve the `group()` method, it will return the relationship object, not perform any queries and fetch the relating object.

Also, Eloquent will make assumptions as to what your foreign key column names are. `Group` would automatically translate to a `group_id` column. If you have an existing column called `group`, then you should specify that explicitly in your relationship:

```
public function group () 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Group', 'group');
}
```

If you receive a "Trying to get property of non-object" error for the property `group`, then your relationship is not returning any results (`$user->group` will be `NULL`). At that point, you should make sure your relationship is set up properly (e.g. using the correct belongsTo, hasOne, hasMany, etc.), and ensure that you actually have a related entry in your database.

Comment: I have tried that but get the error `Trying to get property of non-object` using `User::find(1)->group->name`

Comment: Then your relationship is not returning any results. Make sure you have a group attached to that employee.

Comment: But when I retrieve the relation using `group()` I can see the relevant user in the protected `attributes` property so surely the data is being retrieved?

Comment: `$employee->group()` will return the `BelongsTo` class; it won't perform any queries or find any related users or groups.

Make sure you have a `group_id` column in your `users` table, otherwise this relationship won't work.

Comment: Added info about the table name to the answer.

Comment: I have added the second parameter to the `belongsTo` function `$this->belongsTo('Group', 'group');` and there is a relationship in the database. The only user has a `group` of **1** and the group with an `id` of **1** exists. However, I still get the same error. Adding screenshots to OP now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58297/discussion-between-cryode-and-carl-markham).

Comment: Plus one and accepted for helping on chat and solving the issue.