# How to insert record with many belongsTo relations in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I am trying to insert record in Eloquent way.

It is clear in basic cases. For example if I have a Blog with Posts and each post belongs to a User I can do this:

```
$post = new Post;
$post->content = 'Post content';
$user->posts()->save($post);
```

But how should I do this if my Post belongs to User, Category and Group at the same time?

My first idea was to do it this way:

```
$post = new Post;
$post->content = 'Post content';
$user->posts()->save($post);
$group->posts()->associate($post);
$cat->posts()->associate($post);
```

But it doesn't work, because group id and category id are null when I save it to the DB and it is not allowed.

What I am doing now is:

```
$post = new Post;
$post->content = 'Post content';
$post->group = $group->id;
$post->category = $cat->id;
$user->posts()->save($post);
```

But I don't think it is the right way.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Just save your category and group before trying to associate. `$group->save();`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving related records in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23228694/saving-related-records-in-laravel)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're using `associate` the wrong way around. You have to call it on the `belongsTo` relation side not the `hasMany`.

Try this:

```
$post = new Post;
$post->content = 'Post content';
$post->category()->associate($cat);
$post->group()->associate($group);
$user->posts()->save($post);
```

Comment: It makes sense, but I can;t get it working. In my Post model I have a relation "belongsTo" called group(). But when I do $post->group()->associate($group); I get "Undefined property group" error. I will keep working on it and let you know.

Comment: Hmm can you update your question with the relationship definitions? Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: I think I found out why I am having this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026123/laravel-belongs-to-throwing-undefined-error

Comment: Ah yes, you can't do that. If it's `group` is the foreign key I suggest you name it `group_id` (then you don't even have to define it in the relation since you're following the convention)

Comment: Yup, this was the problem. So your solution was perfect. Thanks a lot Lukas! :)